# JAWS is reading the form labels twice instead of single time

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, wcag

I faced some strange behavior with the JAWS reader where it was reading the question labels twice.

In the below code, I added an aria-labelledby for the radio group which referenced the question id from the 'p' tag.

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <p id="question1">What is your favourite color? <span class="sr-only">select one color</span></p>
  <div class="radio-group" role="radiogroup" aria-labelledby="question1">

  ... radio button 1 ... 
... radio button 1 ... 
... radio button 1 ... 

  </div> 
</div>
```

Am I missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Can you be more precise ? How do you navigate exactly ? Are you using arrow keys or tab ? Having the actual code for radio buttons as well would be helpful, too, especially if you notice the  label being read twice when landing on the radio buttons.

Comment: I am not using any tabs to navigate and enabling the reader when the page loads and allows it to read automatically. So it is reading like : 'what is your favorite color' followed by 'select one color' followed by 'group what is your favorite color'. This is not happening when I tab keys.

Comment: If you put the p *inside* the group, does it solve your issue? That’s how the corresponding semantic HTML `<fieldset>` would do.

Comment: @Andy, nope that doesn't solve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't missing anything. If you navigate in the page with arrow keys using the virtual (browse) cursor, you effectively read "What is your favorite color ?" twice.

- The first time is for the paragraph
- The second time is for the div with role radiogroup, which references the previous seen paragraph as a label

You can make it be read only once, but I strongly discourage you to go for any of these solutions, as they are all bad:

- Simply remove aria-labelledby
  Problem: "what is your favorite color ?" won't be read anymore if the user navigates with tab
- Remove the paragraph and put "What is your favorite color ?" directly in aria-label.
  Problem: sighted users won't see it anymore
- Put the paragraph off-screen with CSS.
  Problem: same as above
- Set the paragraph to be display:none
  Problem: same as above, and additionally it's kind of borderline design: it will probably work with some screen readers, but not with some others. The behavior isn't well specified in that case.

Side question: why are you using `<div role=radiogroup">` instead of `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`  ?
It would certainly be better if you could use the later.